# Push Notification using Azure From .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-notificationhub

This is my code. Please help me. I had User and Context class. So I can connect my database.And I can run my code and get the 'Success' result too. However, I could not receive any notification yet.
My reference is Windows but still ı can not understand what's the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
using Apns2;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        string hubName = "a";
        string connectionString = "b";


        using (Context c = new Context())
        {
            
            var user = c.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == 231 && u.DeviceType == "iPhone");
            if (user != null)
            {
                string deviceId = user.DeviceId;

                // Kullanıcı bilgilerinin kontrol edilmesi.
                Console.WriteLine($"User Name: {user.FirstName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Id: {user.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"DeviceType: {user.DeviceType}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Device Id: {user.DeviceId}");

                Console.WriteLine("Bildirim gönderiliyor...");

                // Bildirim gönderme işlemi.
                await SendNotificationToDevice(hubName, connectionString, deviceId);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Kullanıcı bulunamadı.");
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task SendNotificationToDevice(string hubName, string connectionString, string deviceId)
    {
        NotificationHubClient hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, hubName);

        string appleNotification = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello from Azure Notification Hubs!\"}}";

        try
        {
            await hubClient.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(appleNotification, deviceId);
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Sended!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Bildirim gönderirken bir hata oluştu: {ex.Message}");
        }`your text`
    }

}
```